# Proof of Marriage for independent Finnish Residence Permit

Tags: residency, finland, permits

My wife currently lives in Finland and she has a valid Residence Permit. Now recently I am in talks with a company to move there with an Independent Residence permit. But however, when I am filling up the respective form at enterfinland.fi e-services, it's asking me whether my spouse lives in Finland or not?

In case, I say yes and provide all her details; during my interview at the Finnish embassy, will I be asked to submit my marriage certificate or any other proofs regarding me and my spouse?

The reason for this question is that my Marriage Certificate is not notarised and I am not sure should I take up this hassle of notarising, within a short duration of time. I legally married my wife in India.

Comment: If you answer no, surely you’d have to invent a non-Finnish address for her? Which would be 2 lies.

Answer (score 3):

You should tell the truth, and if that means a little extra hassle getting your marriage certificate notarised, then so be it.

Your alternative is to lie. If the Finnish authorities catch on they'll refuse you a permit and likely ban you for a protracted period.

Never lie to immigration officers. It **will** come back to bite you.